# Read the null value in Python Redmine API

Tags: odoo, redmine, redmine-api, python-redmine

Using rest API, I am connecting Redmine with Python Script and Populating the data in the ODOO.

In Redmine assigned_to value in issue is empty i.e NULL, while Reading those value.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vignesh/PycharmProjects/vignesh/vigred.py", line 23, in <module>
    redmine_asssigned_to = id.assigned_to
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_redmine-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/redmine/resources.py", line 424, in __getattr__
    return super(Issue, self).__getattr__(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_redmine-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/redmine/resources.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    return self._action_if_attribute_absent()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_redmine-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/redmine/resources.py", line 294, in _action_if_attribute_absent
    raise ResourceAttrError
redmine.exceptions.ResourceAttrError: Resource doesn't have the requested attribute
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Use `getattr(id, 'assigned_to', None)` instead of `id.assigned_to`.

Long answer: Python-Redmine raises `ResourceAttrError` if you're trying to access an attribute that doesn't exist. The problem here is that `assigned_to` may or may not exist on the resource object depending on if it is set in Redmine or not, also Python-Redmine doesn't hardcode any attributes inside itself, i.e. it gets them dynamically from Redmine, that is why you have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation